# how can i change the width of an dropdown list as his actually input size

Tags: html, css, ember.js, input

im programming a backend system with emberjs and i use the ember select for dropdowns.

the problem that i have is that the list has the same width of the input field.

is their an way to give the list a nother width as the input? In dev tools it looks like that the width is given dynamicly (pic 2)

i didn't found a solution, to change the width dynamicly so it fits to the content in the list

[image: ember dropdown]

[image]

that's how it should look like

[image: final]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the items in the list - this will force the text to remain on a single line.

Untested since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: it will push them to one line, but it will not change the width. It's the same

Comment: Then you'll need to post your code as snippets so I can see what needs to be changed.